# type safe wrapper class in typescript

Tags: typescript, oop, types, prototype, wrapper

I'm trying to create a wrapper class. I have a `Base` class from an imported package and want to wrap it with some logging and try/catch, in such a way that the `Wrapper` class is fully abstracted away from the user, and can be used as if using the `Base` class. What I have so far:

```js
class Base {
    name: string;

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    first() {}
    second(val: number) {}
    third(vals: number[]) {}
    ... // a lot of methods, can't map them manually
}

class Wrapper {
    bases: Base[] = [];

    constructor(names: string[]) {
        for (const name of names) {
            this.bases.push(new Base(name));
        }
    }
}

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Base.prototype).forEach((methodName) => {
    if (methodName !== 'constructor') {
        Wrapper.prototype[methodName] = function (...args) {
            for (const base of this.bases) {
                try {
                    // logging 
                    return base[methodName].apply(base, args);
                } catch {}
            }
        };
    }
});
```

The problem with this is that I get some type warnings:

- `No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Wrapper'`
- `No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Base'`

and ignoring those, the wrapper class doesn't inherit the `Base` type, so that if I do

```js
const wrapper = new Wrapper(['a', 'b', 'c']);
const s = wrapper.first();
```

I get `Property 'first' does not exist on type 'Wrapper'`.

Is there a better way to ensure type safety besides overriding manually the type `as unknown as Base`? I could extend the `Base` class though I would miss some class properties, such as `name` in this example.

EDIT: added some more examples of method in `Base` class. The `Base` class is quite large, so there are lot of different methods, including with optional parameters, overloads, etc

Comment: If you want to use this approach you're definitely going to have to use type assertions somewhere, or other type loosening, since TS doesn't track such out-of-band mutations to prototypes.  With the example as written I would do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mb1MdN). Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I think that's definitely a good step but still gives errors if eg you add `first(a: number)` , then `Wrapper.prototype[methodName]` gives a type warning

Comment: So please [edit] to provide a [mre] with enough structure to encompass your use cases, otherwise it's hard to guess what kinds of things you might try as next steps once the example code has been addressed.

Comment: Added some more examples!

Comment: I think if you mostly care about the experience of those using `Wrapper` instances and not guaranteeing type safety inside your implementation of it, then [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WY2MEw) might be what you need.  Can you test against your use cases and let me know if I should write up an answer, or if you can [edit] to augment the example with something that fails?  Thanks.

Comment: that works for my use case!

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we care more about the experience of those *using* `Wrapper` and less about the TypeScript compiler being able to verify that we have *implemented* `Wrapper` properly, I would be inclined to proceed like this:

First, let's determine which properties of `Base` we need to copy over into `Wrapper`.  It looks like it's supposed to be all the methods.  TypeScript can't really tell the difference between a method (on the prototype) and a function-valued property (on each instance) so I'm hoping you don't have any of the latter.  We can use a [key-remapped mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to filter the properties of an object to just the function properties:

```
type FuncsOf<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends Function ? K : never]: T[K]
}
```

Then, we can [merge](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) `FuncsOf<Base>` into the `Wrapper` instance type:

```
interface Wrapper extends FuncsOf<Base> { }
```

This tells TypeScript that a `Wrapper` instance also is assignable to `FuncsOf<Base>`, without requiring or caring that it's actually implemented anywhere.  This is a bit dangerous, since if you forgot to write your loop over `Base.prototype` entries, or if you wrote it incorrectly, the compiler won't know or care.  But I'm not worried about that here because as I said at the top, we're focusing on the users of `Wrapper` and not the implementer.  We'll just have to be careful with the implementation.

And since that's the case, I'm just going to use [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) and [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to sidestep any compiler errors inside this loop:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Base.prototype).forEach((methodName) => {
  if (methodName !== 'constructor') {
    (Wrapper.prototype as any)[methodName] = function (...args: any) {
      for (const base of this.bases) {
        try {
          // logging 
          return base[methodName].apply(base, args);
        } catch { }
      }
    };
  }
});
```

There are ways to begin to try to write this so the compiler checks the loop more closely, but frankly they are more trouble than they're worth.  (If you're interested in going down the rabbit hole, you can look at [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) to get a flavor of the kinds of typing gymnastics involved.)

---

Anyway, let's try it out:

```
const wrapper = new Wrapper(['a', 'b', 'c']);
const s = wrapper.first(); // okay
wrapper.second(2); // okay
wrapper.third([1, 2, 3]); // okay
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8BQ1oDswFsEC5oIAXAJwEtMBzAblXWmAHtMTSBXYYp0gCmzyE2lKgEoUDDMQAW5CADoBSALxZcCOhgC+9DADNypEr3HJoOjBATNMAE14A3MCEKZ2OAEYJSp8wxmG9k4gEK7uXqQA2gC6vjo6qMQAngAOSABi7JjAEADyegA8ACoAfNCqaBiRANLQlNAA1ghJTHrQRdCQ7TXR0AgAHsQIdjCZ2cTkLNAA-NC1rggO3tGERT2oOpRDpHpgwEgA6qRgKWmkfYPDtqNZOfkF8FZlZgmgkDBHJ2cSGB6IoXBEDFytAYnQGDY2JxuHwlADhNQYqZJNA9DxoLxIcQ1HhoK0cQgIMiMCToAEFH8rAoUuwINJ+AgAO6Aqz8dSiUSaEkWPwJXIeABW1mI8ioCGIuUZmAACqQmGdkgA5dQQXiPBDyFJy7jJNKieRo0gAUT29N4eBkTFsyrw4mUzwY5Da5vF0itNqQAEJlKoAORYjhcHi+4kk3ifU7eTXapi6pBdMCYJKiSIWt3W9S9VR6W4TKa8eSFsCkKgAxPJn6k1HozEsEjQSlIfHk+SNomVqtk0hJFCd0kozukcXsUiYBtAtPuzPyL4gJK8RsAGk6JaJXM7WkYYGIwGkvZ5pIP5i58U59Cx0EZx0j51UmCZ0AjZ14kV9YF9y99Hg-0H9vtidAXjAqhXl8UYGEYxAmDQ0AAPSwXiDRgEkqCgTe8hWDY9gAEycnBCFMEhKFoWc8gBKQ9iRAAjMu2HLgAzAB+GIch9BsUAA)